# Прокрутка PDF-файла на сайте при помощи тега embed или iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pdf

Скролл средствами JS или jQuery pdf-файла, помещенного на сайт при помощи тега `embed` или `iframe` или любым другим способом.

Можно ли?

Comment: Хм, а разве скролить iframe с помошью js нельзя?

Comment: Конкретно в случае с pdf файлом, вставленным при помощи iframe не получилось, по всякому пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, судя по всему невозможно. Для решения задачи использовал библиотеку `PDF.js`, позволяющую вставлять pdf на сайт без помощи `iframe` и `embed`. В заданной изначально формулировке решить задачу не удалось.